# How to pick a random direction in n-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

I want to pick a random direction in n-dimensional space.  How can I do this?

The reason I want to do this is to pick a neighbor for [hill climbing optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can proceed as explained at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this efficiently is to rely on the fact that a gaussian distribution is spherically symmetric and also separable. So, what you need to do is :

1) Build a vector V where each element is a Gaussian distributed value of mean 0, choose any width that makes sense.

2) Normalize the vector V

This vector now is a random unit vector uniformly distributed across the hypersphere of the vector V. This algorithm is both fast and is linear in the dimension of V.

Comment: The Box–Muller transform may be used to generate independent pairs of normally distributed variables from independent pairs of (continuous) uniformly distributed ones (with no 'waste').

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to pick $n$ random numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ from the interval [-1,1].  If $\sum x_i^2 > 1$ throw those numbers out and try again.  Otherwise, rescale so that $\sum x_i^2 = 1$.

For large $n$ this is inefficient with computer time (because $\sum x_i^2 > 1$ most of the time), but it might be more efficient with your time (because it's easy to program).

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Can you give or refer to a proof?  Anyway, I think the usual approach of "generate $n$ iid standard Gaussian and divide the resulting vector by its norm" is simpler to program and faster to run.

Comment: Those $\sum x_i$ are supposed to be $\sum x_i^2$.

Comment: @Ben: Oops, you're right.  That's what I meant but apparently not what I typed.  Fixed now.

@Nate: Does it sound right after the correction?  I'm just choosing a random point in the unit ball and rescaling.

Comment: It sounds right. It also sounds truly inefficient ... in high dimensions you will have to sample a ridiculously large number of points to get one that works.

Comment: Indeed, you should expect $(n/2)!(\pi/2)^{-n/2}$ trials before success.  For $n=10$ it's about 1000, and for $n=100$... let's just say, too many.

Comment: Yes, as I noted in the 2nd paragraph this is inefficient for large $n$, but in applications $n$ is not always large.  I've employed this method when $n=3$.  In this case I suspect it's faster than using Gaussian distributions.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Scientific Library (GSL) has an implementation for this.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Spherical-Vector-Distributions.html in the manual.  It even refers to where Knuth describes the algorithm.